# Запускается ahk файл, но с ошибкой Error: This line does not contain a recognized action

Tags: python, ahk

Запускается ahk файл, но с ошибкой
Error: This line does not contain a recognized action.
Text:   #Persistent
Line:   1

```html
#Persistent
SetTimer, toggle_ahk_script, 1000
return
FileAppend, % "C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\python-show-text\\kliker.py"
toggle_ahk_script:
IfWinExist, Простая игра кликера
{
    ControlClick, toggle_ahk_script, Простая игра кликера
}
return
```

```
import subprocess
import keyboard

ahk_script = "skript.ahk"
ahk_process = None

ahk_exe = r"C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\v2\AutoHotkey.exe"
ahk_process = subprocess.Popen([ahk_exe, ahk_script])
def toggle_ahk_script():
    global ahk_process
    if ahk_process:
        ahk_process.terminate()  # Останавливаем скрипт AHK
        ahk_process = None
        print("AHK скрипт остановлен")
    else:
        ahk_process = subprocess.Popen(['autohotkey', ahk_script])  # Запускаем скрипт AHK
        print("AHK скрипт запущен")

keyboard.add_hotkey('1', toggle_ahk_script)

print("Нажмите '1' для запуска/остановки AHK скрипта. Нажмите ESC для выхода.")
keyboard.wait('esc')
```